# Php Input Validation not responding

Tags: php, html, validation

I am new to the web developing world.Please bare w/ me for having some mistakes and insufficient knowledge.

I'm trying to study the validation process of a users input. Below is my Code:

```
<?php

if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Search") 
{
  $errorMessage = "";

  if(empty($_POST['formName'])) 
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>No Input</li>";
  }

  $varName = $_POST['formName'];

  if(!empty($errorMessage)) 
  {
    echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
    echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
  } 

}

?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="formName" value="<?=$varName;?>">
<input type="Submit" name="formSubmit" value=" Search">
</form>
```

What I think should happen is when the user click the search button without inputting anything an error message will pop-up, but I don't understand why its not responding or echoing the error message, i've check the names and values but Alas, Appreciate all the help/suggestions you could give tnx.

Thanks for the reply everyone, got it into working ^_^

Comment: The value of your submit button has an extra space in front, so the if block doesn't execute.

Comment: Also if you just compare `$_POST['formSubmit']` in a `if` and for any reason someone doesn't pass any parameter with that name it will pop a warning. To avoid this you can check if any value was passed or not before comparing it using `isset()`

Answer (score 1):

Your `$_POST['formSubmit']` doesn't contain `Search`. It contains `Search` (with space in front of it).

Because of that PHP will never validate your form.

Comment: wow didn't see that coming thank you sir, I feel like a total loser haha. It worked, Love this community thanks

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<?php

if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Search") 
{
  $errorMessage = "";

  if(empty($_POST['formName'])) 
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>No Input</li>";
  }

  $varName = $_POST['formName'];

  if(!empty($errorMessage)) 
  {
    echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
    echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
  } 

}

?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="formName" value="<?=$varName;?>">
<input type="Submit" name="formSubmit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use isset() function

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) 
{
  $errorMessage = "";

  if(empty($_POST['formName'])) 
  {
   echo $errorMessage .= "No Input";
  }
 else
 {
    $varName = $_POST['formName'];
 } 

}

 ?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="formName" value="<?=$varName;?>">
<input type="Submit" name="formSubmit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: still got the typo :p second line.

Answer (score 0):

You giving wrong name to your submit button .

```
<input type="Submit" name="formSubmit" value=" Search">
```

it should be

```
<input type="Submit" name="formSubmit" value="Search">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Search") 

to

if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am making some corrections. Please use this.

```
<?php
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Search") {
    $errorMessage = "";
    if(empty($_POST['formName'])) {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>No Input</li>";
    } else {
        $varName = $_POST['formName'];
    }
    if(!empty($errorMessage)) {
        echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
        echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
    } 
}
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="formName" value="<?=$varName;?>">
    <input type="Submit" name="formSubmit" value="Search">
</form>
```

1. Corrected the condition if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Search")
2. IF $_POST['formName'] is empty then no need for assigning so put it inside else condition.